# Make the mid item bigger with inline-grid

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a grid for each plan for my hosting company. But I can't figure out one thing. How can I make the item in the middle appear to be bigger in height than the other two, for my hosting grid?

Code snippet:

```css
.Hosting {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.Hosting>li {
  display: inline-grid;
  width: calc(33% - 15px);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px #c3d7ef;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px #c3d7ef;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #c3d7ef;
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="Hosting">
  <li>
    <h2>
      Small
      <small>10.99€</small>
    </h2>

    <ul>
      <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Item</li>
    </ul>

    <a href="" class="Order"><button>Order Now</button></a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <h2>
      Small
      <small>10.99€</small>
    </h2>

    <ul>
      <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Item</li>
    </ul>

    <a href="" class="Order"><button>Order Now</button></a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <h2>
      Small
      <small>10.99€</small>
    </h2>

    <ul>
      <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Item</li>
    </ul>

    <a href="" class="Order"><button>Order Now</button></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I have tried to set the height and margins of them but it doesn't seem to work. Because it's inline-grid, but I believe that is the best way of showing my plans? I'm not a big fan of using floats.

Any idea on how I can achieve this?

Comment: Can you post the illustration? Is it something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYcCS.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use css property `transform:scale(1.2)` on item you want to show bigger than other two!!